# MVC application has two cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In release environment, my mvc application has two set of cookies. Lets say the site name is **test-solution.com**, the cookies created are as follows:

**1) test-solution.com**

**2) [www.test-solution.com](http://www.test-solution.com)**

Following is the code for writing cookie:

```
        HttpCookie UserToken = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserToken"];
        if (UserToken == null)
        {
            UserToken = new HttpCookie("UserToken");
            UserToken.Values["Token"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Session["UserToken"] = UserToken.Values["Token"];
        #if RELEASE
                   UserToken.Secure = true;
        #endif
        UserToken.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        #if RELEASE
                   HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["UserToken"].Path += ";SameSite=Lax;";  
        #endif
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(UserToken);
```

I just intend to have one ([www.test-solution.com](http://www.test-solution.com)) cookie rather than two.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for these two cookies is that my website was referring to a google-analytics script and this was implicitly creating another cookie.